# Adding elements to an Array using a special loop for iteration

Tags: php, arrays, loops, for-loop, iteration

Supposing I have an `Array` with `x` elements. I would like to loop through this `Array` in "tens" and add a `run-Time` variable. This means that each set of 10 `Arrays` will have a unique `run-time`. I am using the code below:

```
$time = '00:00:00';
 $k = 0;
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($agnt_arr); $i+=10) {
        $temp = strtotime("+$k minutes", strtotime($time));
        $runTime = date('H:i', $temp);
        array_push($agnt_arr[$i], $runTime);
        $k+=4;
    }
```

Where `$agnt_arr` is an `Array` with the following structure :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => User.One 
            [email] => User.One@mail.com
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => User.Two 
            [email] => User.Two@mail.com
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => User.Three 
            [email] => User.Three@mail.com
        )
)
```

The problem I'm having is the run times are only added to the 10th element which is expected But I would like elements 0-9 to have the same run time and 10-20 etc. How would I achieve something like this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably easier like this always adding runtime but updating it for each 10:

```
$time = '00:00:00';
foreach($agent_arr as $key => $value) {
    if($key % 10 === 0) {
        $temp = strtotime("+$k minutes", strtotime($time));
        $runTime = date('H:i', $temp);
    }
    $agent_arr[$key]['runtime'] = $runTime;
}
```

Comment: I think you've left out the updating of the `$k` variable.

Comment: This is very neat. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my overcomplicated solution(and probably unnecessary):

```
$new_array = array();

foreach(array_chunk($array, 10 /* Your leap number would go here */) as $k => $v)
{
    array_walk($v, function($value, $key) use (&$new_array){
        $value['time'] = $time;
        $new_array[] = $value;
    });
}
```